# MSE changed windows firewall settings and win server 2008 r2 can not be access by it's name anymore

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall, fqdn

i have installed Microsoft Security Essentials on Win server 2008 R2 and it modified the Windows firewall, this caused an access problem, win server 2008 R2 can not be accessed by it's name anymore and i turned Public Networks off on firewall, now i can access, i dont know what causes the problem, can you help me?

thanks

Comment: do you use dns for name resolution, or its netbios broadcast ?

Comment: AFAIK, MSE isn't supported on Windows Server 2008 R2. My suggestion would be to uninstall it and install something that is supported.

Comment: @yagmoth555, it is netbios broadcast, there is no AD, DNS etc.

Comment: @joeqwerty, but it works no errors, what can i install? i need something doesnt ride the server like a horse.

Comment: There aren't 'no errors', you've broken the whole setup!  If there were 'no errors' then your  server would work properly...

Answer (score 0):

Set your firewall to a private profile, or be sure those rule in the 'Advance' section are allowed. (The one in red and the other for File and Printing Sharing are allowed)

[image]

Comment: they are all set to Allow, but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @washaq Check the outbound rule too, but I suggest using private network, not the public profile.